# Why do the arguments in PHP's array_udiff() comparison function not always stay "in order"?

Tags: php

Recently I was trying to use PHP's `array_udiff()` function to compare a value in a multi-dimensional array with a plain old string value. I tried something like this:

```php
// E.g. $employees[0]["name"] = "Jeff";
//      $currentEmployeeName  = "Steve";
// This won't work because $a doesn't always correspond to $employees
array_udiff($employees, $currentEmployeeName, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a["name"], $b);
}
```

This returned errors like "attempting to use string $a as array" or similar.

I quickly discovered a comment which explained:

> Something interesting to note, is that the two arguments to the
> compare function don't correspond to array1 and array2.  That's why
> there has to be logic in it to handle that either of the arguments
> might be pointing to the more complex array.
> - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php#80149

The working solution therefore had to determine which of the parameters was the array:

```php
// Will work
array_udiff($employees, $currentEmployeeName, function ($a, $b) {
    $aVal = is_array($a) ? $a["name"] : $a;
    $bVal = is_array($b) ? $b["name"] : $b;
    return strcasecmp($aVal, $bVal);
}
```

My question is: why does `array_udiff()` work like this? Why don't the parameters in the comparison function always correspond to the same order as the arrays being compared?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is, since it can be interpreted two different ways: "Why is this happening?" (The answer is: because the person who wrote `array_udiff()` decided to implement it that way) or "Why did  the person who wrote `array_udiff()` decide to implement it that way?" (Which is a question that can only be answered by that person).

Comment: @JörgWMittag "because the person who wrote `array_udiff()` decided to implement it that way" - yes, but there will also be a _technical_ explanation which is clearly what the OP is asking about. More info here: https://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/11/php-arrayudiff.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [blog post](https://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/11/php-arrayudiff.html) linked in comment by @user7290573 (and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21096613/1652951) on StackOverflow) I discovered that the function actually sorts the arrays before filtering.

This is why the arrays aren't necessarily kept in the same order as passed in the function call.

Because of the sorting, the callback function also requires a full comparison (-1, 0, 1) of the values being compared to function correctly.

Hope this helps someone in the future who might not be aware of the quirks of this function.